# Add a plugin source before using its method with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding a countdown plugin with jquery but after calling the main method to start the countdown console says countdown method is not found (which is the main method of starting the plugin). If i run the code twice, the countdown starts. That means I have to load jquery plugin source before executing the main command.

Here is my code:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://www.test.gr/images/promo/monetate_js/jquery.countdown.min.js';
$('head').append(script);

var script2 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script2.type = 'text/javascript';
script2.src = 'http://www.test.gr/images/promo/monetate_js/jquery.plugin.min.js';
$('head').append(script2);

$('.omgtest').before("<div class='countdownclock'></div>");
$('.countdownclock').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 8 - 1, 8)});
```

I thought of using callback function like this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://www.test.gr/images/promo/monetate_js/jquery.countdown.min.js';

var script2 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script2.type = 'text/javascript';
script2.src = 'http://www.test.gr/images/promo/monetate_js/jquery.plugin.min.js';

$("head").append(script,function(){
    $("head").append(script2,function(){
        $( ".omgtest").before("<div class='countdownclock'></div>",function(){
            $('.countdownclock').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 8 - 1, 8)});
        });
    });
});
```

but that did not work either.

I created a jsfiddle to test it (http://jsfiddle.net/UJmDu/1/). But of course it will never work cause the links in src are not the real one (sorry cant use the real ones). So Im betting someone could help mostly by seeing my code. If I could add something to my post to help someone help me please let me know. Also this is the link of the plugin page (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Scripts are loaded asynchronously here. You could use onload callback of specific script or just use the regular way to load scripts

Comment: Both scripts should load to make it work thats why I call them this way. Regular way to load scripts is not acceptable, strange I know.

Comment: `append()` is a sync method, it doesn't accept any callback. Like i said, use onload callback of script to set logic, e.g: `script.onload = function(){('.omgtest').before("<div class='countdownclock'></div>");
$('.countdownclock').countdown({until: new Date(2014, 8 - 1, 8)}); };`. If you need to wait for both script to be loaded, then set logic according to it, as using e.g a boolean flag set to true once both script has been loaded. On modern browsers, i guess you could set `script.async = false;`

Comment: thanks man I'll try it live and let you know